# Does rsync have to be installed on the remote server?

Tags: rsync, remote

I have `rsync` installed on a machine. I am trying to sync a directory to a remote machine. Sometimes, on some remote machines, it works; but sometimes it doesn't.

Does `rsync` have to be installed on the remote machine as well? Or is this not necessary?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to install `rsync` in both source and destination machine.

`rsync` works by doing quick calculations at both ends looking at the timestamps and existence of all the found files in a particular location. Once it does this, it communicates back to the origin `rsync` about the found list and the origin can then use that information to decide what files it needs to send.

That way only the recently modified or new files get transmitted to the other side. The `rsync` binary on the remote side is responsible for getting the list together of what already exists and then receiving each of the files that need to be transmitted and putting them in place.

Comment: Thanks, I don;t know this before..
So, if we use `scp` then, does it needs to be installed on both?

Comment: yes even scp need to be exist on both machines

Comment: Oh! Then how we will get to know either `scp` or `rsync` is present at remote side or not? Which package is installed by default by Linux/UNIX OS?

Comment: `scp` is generally installed by default on most linux distros as a part of openssh packages. On ubuntu/debian for example, the openssh-client package provides the scp program

Comment: @WissamAl-Roujoulah `scp` does not need to be installed on the destination machine, however an SSH server must be running (`sshd`) on it.

Comment: @stevieb did you try it ?